# Mini-world as table in a relational database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

In relational databases, if we want to create a database for a football **tournament** for example, we consider the tournament as the mini-world (the unit for which we want to create a database and collect data). Therefore, we may create tables such as matches, teams, and so on. And, we don't create a table called **tournament** since we have only THE TOURNAMENT for which we are doing all this.

In practice, that's what I used to do. But, what if I want to save in my database some attributes about the tournament, such as its name, the date and the country in which it takes place... What can I do? Is it a good practice to create a table **tournament** that has only one record? And if yes, what about foreign keys? Is it good in this case to add the ID of the tournament as a foreign key in the tables matches, teams...? If not, what can be the best practice?

Why I want to store the tournament information in the database? Because I want to create a webpage that reads only dynamic data. I don't want to add those information (tournament name, date...) as static data on the web page.

I am also thinking about the benefit from the possibility of future evolution of the product. Later on, I may have more than one tournament and having the tournament table part of the database will allow a smooth integration of more tournaments without modification of the metadata.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is typical to use a row to store relevant single values. (Frequently this is done for parameter settings). But you don't need an id in this row for the tournament or foreign keys to it in other tables until you have multiple tournaments.

Yes, this helps extend to multiple tournaments. It also helps in extending to a "temporal"/historical version of the database where we timestamp each row by when it held so that we can query about the state that was current at a given time. (This typically involves further normalization to have separate tables for columns that change together but possibly at different times from other column sets.)

In moving to multiple tournaments, as with any schema change, it is helpful to redefine the names of old tables as views of new tables. Unfortunately updates through views are typically poorly supported by SQL DBMSs so in that respect it can be useful to have a multiple-tournament-capable design right from the beginning.

Comment: IMO you should just assume more than 1 tournament will happen. Minimal effort to add an ID now, compared to changing everything after. Maybe this code can be reused somewhere else.